# Как убрать числа из строки на java?

Tags: java, строки

Мне нужно убрать числа из строки оставить пробелы и все остальные символы и добавить в переменную `justWords`, что бы при выводе на экран получилась строка:

> Just words: JDK has released on September with new features, feature removals and feature deprecations.

Вот мой код:

```
public class ParseIntegers {

    private static final List<String> WORDS = Arrays.asList(
            "JDK 17 has released on 14 September 2021 with 10 new features, 2 feature removals and 2 feature deprecations."
            .split(" "));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterator<String> words = WORDS.iterator();
       
        String justWords = "";
     
        for (String forJustWord : WORDS) {
            if (forJustWord.matches("\\D+")) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Just words:" + justWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще применить к начальной строке операцию `String::replaceAll`:

```java
String str = "JDK 17 has released on 14 September 2021 with 10 new features, 2 feature removals and 2 feature deprecations.";

String justWords = str.replaceAll("\\d+ ", ""); // убрать цифры и один пробел  после них

System.out.println(justWords);
// -> JDK has released on September with new features, feature removals and feature deprecations.
```

---

Если нужно проверить и отфильтровать слова в списке `WORDS`, можно применить Stream API:

```java
String justWords = WORDS.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches("\\D+")) // или !s.matches("\\d+")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, через replaseAll отличный способ.